# Aligning two tables with different number of rows inside a parent table

Tags: html-table, html-email

Inside a parent table, I have `table1`(with 3 rows) and `table2`(with 2 rows). I need `table2` to align at the top with `table1` and right now its centering `table2`. I know about divs and float but this page is getting sent through a mail server and it renders the page all weird and I have to use tables.

I tried to post some images of my code but its saying I need at least 10 reputations to post images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding valign="top" on your parent table td elements as the default vertical alignment is center or middle for td elements

```
<table id="parent">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table id="table1"></table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table id="table2"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```